# org mode table formatting issue

Tags: org-mode, org-table

Using a simple keyboard macro, I copied the [Font Awesome Cheat Sheet](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/) into an org table. However, I experience some weird inconsistencies when it comes to the formatting - see the picture below:

[image: org table formatting issue]

Any ideas how that happens and how to fix it?

Comment: If you put the cursor in the table and TAB, the columns should automatically align. That's the default behavior for `org-mode`.

Comment: @EmacsUser I did that. The above is the alignment I got. (Prior to that, it looked way worse.)

Comment: In case anyone wants to try it themselves, [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByqvTqmmvRalVjFfV3pTZEVnVWM) is a link to the org file on Google Drives.

Comment: Hi, I tried and the table looks aligned in my system: Mac Os X Yosemite, emacs 24.5.1

Comment: @iluvatar Are all symbols displayed correctly? (I ask, because it's certainly aligned if you don't have awesome fonts installed.)

Comment: What is interesting is that the table is aligned when running emacs on a terminal (no gui) but not aligned when running on the gui. I do not know why.

Answer (score 3):

Org-mode table formatting assumes a true fixed-width font.

Many Unicode glyphs have odd sizes; check for example *fa-chevron-left* by setting the cursor there and comparing its size to other standard characters.

I personally don't know of a fixed-width font across all characters.

Comment: That's what I expected. Is there a workaround?

Comment: On my Linux system I tried both the Ubuntu Mono font and the Fira Mono font and in both cases only the final column of `|`s looks ragged. The vertical bars between the columns are ok (although the vertical bars don't align with the horizontal top line. However, these fonts definitely don't cover all symbols.