# org mode table formatting problem

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I'm on Windows 7 using emacs version `GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (i686-pc-mingw32) of 2015-04-11 on LEG570`.

When I create tables with org-mode, I end up having something like this.
[image: misaligned table on row #2].

I searched and found the following questions:

1. [org mode table formatting issue](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/23885/org-mode-table-formatting-issue) - The answer to this question was to use a monospaced (non-propotional font). In my case I'm using `consolas` which is a monospace font. So the answer does not apply.
2. [org-mode table layout](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27333/org-mode-table-layout) - The answer to this question is also to use a monospaced font - So does not apply for my case.
3. [org-mode table editor behaves strangely](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/37804/org-mode-table-editor-behaves-strangely) - This question remains unanswered.

I don't remember from when this thing had broken.  I suspected that the contents (some tag settings etc) might be causing this erratic behaviour and created a new test.org file. It was no different as shown below.
[image].

**Note**: Are there any updates to org-mode which will fix this issue? BTW, my org-version is
`Org mode version 9.1.5 (9.1.5-1-gb3ddb0-elpaplus @ c:/Users/path/to/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/org-plus-contrib-20171225/)` and I have not been able to update my `org-plus-contrib` package since Jan 2018.

Comment: Just to add: is a link [[link][link label]] in included in the table and we used <> to reduce the size of the column in the buffer, it get even worse.

Answer (score 2):

You are on a 2-month old Org stable version. This issue has long been fixed. Try the latest Org stable from **Org Elpa**.

Update Org using instructions on https://orgmode.org/elpa.html.

Comment: This table formatting was working before. I don't know what happened. I will try to update from elpa

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to be with updating the org version as Kaushal Modi pointed out.

Steps to fix this issue:

1. I downloaded the latest `org-plus-contrib-yyyymmdd` from [elpa](https://orgmode.org/elpa/).
   The file is available only in `.tar` extension. (Convert that to ZIP
   [online](https://www.zamzar.com/) if you do not have archive program that can handle tar
   extension)
2. I extracted the ZIP archive into
   `C:\Users\path_to\AppData\Roaming\.emacs.d` directory and restarted
   emacs.
3. After restart, ran `M-x org-version` and the version had changed to
   `9.1.6` from `9.1.5`

This fixed the table formatting issue. (I'm not a 100% sure of the cause of the problem, but this update fixed things, the way they should be)

Comment: Why would you add a duplicate answer? In any case, anyone reading this, there's a simpler way to install the Org package, see https://orgmode.org/elpa.html. Also I am 100% sure that updating Org stable fixed the issue, and so I had answered so.

Comment: In my case, I could not update directly from emacs. I had to download manually and do it. If you think that this could be a duplicate answer, feel free to mark as `not an answer` or `duplicate answer`.

Comment: It does not solve it. New version still have the problem